# uppercase vowel is not read by replace() function

Tags: java

Please help on how to solve this. Im trying to replace small vowel letters to capital letter and here's my code:

```
String text_A = text90n.replace("a", "A");  
String text_E = text_A.replaceAll("e", "E");
String text_I = text_E.replaceAll("i", "I");
String text_O = text_I.replaceAll("o", "O");
String text_U = text_O.replaceAll("u", "U");
```

but it was not working..

the working code to me is just the consonant-vowel pair like this:

```
String text16 = text5q.replaceAll("b=a", "b");
String text17 = text16.replaceAll("b=e", "be");
String text18 = text17.replaceAll("b=i", "bi");
String text19 = text18.replaceAll("b=o", "bo");
String text20 = text19.replaceAll("b=u", "bu");
```

So i guess the main problem to my code is that, it's might not recognizing the capital letters like the first code above.
How can I solve this..? thank you in advance :)

Comment: What's not working? What are you expecting, and what are the actual results?

Comment: The first piece of code should work if all you want to do is capitalize the lower case vowels in your `text90n` string.

Comment: Are you possibly encountering unicode letters with diacriticals or accents, and expecting them to be replaced?

Comment: the  code above is for transliteration.. When i put "umaga" in textview the "ma" and "ga" display its character and the small letter "u" is not recognized. but when i capitalized the "U" the 3 characters shown. So i wonder why the small letter vowel is not replacing by capital letter although i declared it already.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might want to call replaceAll() on text90n, instead of just replace().

Secondly, you can chain these calls which will clean up your code:

```
    String vowelsUpperCased = text90n.replaceAll("A","a").replaceAll("E","e").replaceAll("I","i").replaceAll("O","o").replaceAll("U","u");
```

Comment: the code above is for transliteration.. When i put "umaga" in textview the "ma" and "ga" display its character and the small letter "u" is not recognized. but when i capitalized the "U" the 3 characters shown. So i wonder why the small letter vowel is not replacing by capital letter although i declared it already

Comment: Please provide expected input and expected output and we'll write you some nice code. :)